# to be able to use 3G for internet while connected to wifi?

Tags: wifi

I have a wifi without internet which my iphone connects for a media player only. 
Meanwhile I would like to use my 3g connection for e-mail traffic etc.

I have seen the answers to select the static ip  solution ; (I have an iphone 6)

and yes it works if I connect to wifi at first , then change settings at the wifi connection to static ip and other things etc  , but I have to do it everytime I connect to this network,

is it possible to have a kind of setting to do this once as a set instead of doing it every connection. if not it seems I will buy a used iphone 4 / simple android tablet to do this for me.
Thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You have a new option from iOS 9,

Settings -> Cellular -> Scroll to the bottom of the page -> Wifi-Assist

> Automatically use cellular data when WIFI connectivity is poor

You have some articles about that all around the web
http://appleinsider.com/articles/15/10/14/apple-posts-ios-9-wi-fi-assist-guide-in-wake-of-complaints-about-excessive-data-use
http://www.macworld.com/article/2987233/smartphones/how-to-turn-off-ios-9s-wi-fi-assist-to-save-your-data-plan.html

Comment: I have tried it. The wifi assist dont work for what I would like to do. understand it works if my connection to internet through wifi is poor. My wifi connection is already full coverange as I am only couple of meters away from the wifi spot. As said I have managed to get my request done by ; switching to static ip , entering the same ip address and subnet mask manually and leaving the router and DNS as empty.  Interestingly is it possible to configure the wifi spot so that it requires static ip all the time. I will ask this also at another topic so that some more people can see as a question.